# Why don't charges leak through conductors?

Tags: electrostatics, conductors

Imagine a negatively charged conducting sphere placed in vacuum. Now all the negative charge must be at the surface.

Any electron present at the surface of conductor will experience a net repulsive force due to other charges.

So why doesn't that electron fly off the conductor (but instead remains on the surface)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will in the if you have accumulate enough charge such that the repulsive force overcomes the attraction to the protons in the nucleus.

Comment: But why then electrons can freely flow inside the conductor but not outside?

Comment: It can, but just because you can move freely in two different areas doesn't mean you can freely cross between the areas. You can move freely around on Earth and in space, but it takes quite a bit of work to travel between the two. If you want to know the exact mechanism that's beyond me since it's digging into the details about energy bands and such.

Comment: Got it , thanks

Comment: @IITJEEaspirant They can't. A "real" electron inside a conductor is constantly falling into the potential wells of the ionic lattice. However, such interactions will also transfer energy to nearby electrons and make them move, so they can be seen as replacing the original. The "electrons" that you imagine to move "freely" inside conductors are thus quasiparticles, where the effects of the lattice are folded into redefinitions of the "electron" mass etc, thereby averaging over all the interactions. Making an "electron" into a real electron (by removing it from the lattice) requires energy.

Comment: @HTNW Interesting. So electrons within a material are considered to be in a different form, so to speak, than a free electron? And not just a free electron that has incorporated itself into an atom?